# Gitlab CI conditionally override a template variable based on which files were changes in a MR

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have template that looks like this:

`/templates/.copy-echo.yml`:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'

variables:
  FILE_PATH: /test_conf_1.txt
  DESTINATION_HOST: somehost

stages:
  - copy
  - echo

copy step 1/2:
  rules:
    - changes:
        - ${FILE_PATH}
  stage: copy
  script: |
    echo "Add copy here!"

copy step 2/2:
  rules:
    - changes:
        - ${FILE_PATH}
  stage: echo
  script: |
    printenv
    echo ${DESTINATION_HOST}
```

Now in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
include: '/templates/copy-echo.yml'

variables:
  FILE_PATH: /test_conf_1.txt
  DESTINATION_HOST: somehost2
```

Now what I want is conditionally assign a value to `DESTINATION_HOST` variable depending on which file got changed in merged request.

For e.g. if the merge request had updates to file `test_conf_2.txt` then the value for `DESTINATION_HOST` should be `somehost2` and if the merge request had updates to file `test_conf_3.txt` then the value for `DESTINATION_HOST` should be `somehost3`.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rules:variables`: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesvariables
Example:

```yaml
my job:
  script: printenv
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        - test_conf_2.txt
      variables:
        DESTINATION_HOST: "somehost2"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        - test_conf_3.txt
      variables:
        DESTINATION_HOST: "somehost3"
```

But it doesn't work if you launch pipeline manually:

> You should use rules: changes only with branch pipelines or merge
> request pipelines. You can use rules: changes with other pipeline
> types, but rules: changes always evaluates to true when there is no
> Git push event. Tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, manual pipelines,
> and so on do not have a Git push event associated with them. A rules:
> changes job is always added to those pipelines if there is no if that
> limits the job to branch or merge request pipelines.